# Checking date range against set of date ranges in a data table

Tags: c#, linq, date-range

I need to check a user-entered start and end date against a set of start and end dates in a data table to make sure there are no overlaps.

A user requests time off using a start and end date combination. I want to make sure this start and end date is not contained in a set of dates I have read from DB into a data table.

I have used the following but not sure if this is correct. Here "table" contains user's existing time off requests taken from DB, startDate and endDate is what s/he is requesting. Data table has "StartDate" and "EndDate" columns.

```
private DataTable FilterTable(DataTable table, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var filteredRows =
        from row in table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
        where (DateTime)row["StartDate"] >= startDate
        where (DateTime)row["StartDate"] <= endDate
        select row;

    var filteredTable = table.Clone();
    filteredRows.ToList().ForEach(r => filteredTable.ImportRow(r));
    return filteredTable;
}
```

If the returned data table has no rows, it is OK otherwise there is overlap.

Comment: That only finds overlaps where the start date in the DB is in the given range, but what if the end date is in the range?  Or what if the range in the DB completely contains the given range?

Comment: Basically if R1 starts after R2 or if R2 starts after R1 they don't overlap so the inverse of that is `R1.Start <= R2.End && R2.Start <= R1.End`.  Though you might be OK with the start and ends being equal if they include time, but not if they represent a specific day.

Comment: DataTables aren't great for doing data manipulation with. Maybe consider Hashsets of DateTime objects and using the contains function?

Comment: It is simpler to use : from row in table.AsEnumerable()

Comment: @SamMarion A `HashSet` would be good for finding exact matches, but here the OP needs to do comparisons.

Comment: @juharr How do I modify the function to accomplishwhat I need? Also, this is just dealing with dates, no time (SQL DB field is "date" not "datetime"). I noticed this issue when someone who had already requested 08/19 - 8/22 requested 08/20 - 08/20 and it went through! So date range like 08/16 - 08/21; 08/21 - 08/25; 08/20 - 08/20 should all fail the test. But 08/16 = 08/19 or 08/19 - 08/25 should be OK.

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to check both user-selected start and end dates and see if they fall into date range in data table. If user selected dates are R1 and an entry in data table is R2, I have to check: (R1.StartDate >= R2.StartDate && R1.StartDate <= R2.EndDate) || (R1.EndDate >= R2.StartDate && R1.EndDate <= R2.EndDate) . Does this sound correct?

Comment: No - what if R1.StartDate < R2.StartDate && R1.EndDate > R2.EndDate (e.g. R1 contains R2 completely). They overlap but not according to your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an extension method to check if a Date is between two others,

```
public static class DateTimeExt {
    public static bool Between(this DateTime aDate, DateTime start, DateTime end) => start <= aDate && aDate <= end;
}
```

You can write an Overlaps method that determines if two ranges overlap:

```
public static bool Overlaps(DateTime aPeriodStart, DateTime aPeriodEnd, DateTime bPeriodStart, DateTime bPeriodEnd)
    => aPeriodStart.Between(bPeriodStart, bPeriodEnd) ||
       aPeriodEnd.Between(bPeriodStart, bPeriodEnd) ||
       bPeriodStart.Between(aPeriodStart, aPeriodEnd);
```

Now with another extension method that converts an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` to a `DataTable` containing the rows:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<DataRow> src) {
        var ans = src.First().Table.Clone();
        foreach (var r in src)
            ans.ImportRow(r);
        return ans;
    }    
}
```

Your final method is straight forward:

```
DataTable FilterTable(DataTable timeTable, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) =>
    timeTable.AsEnumerable().Where(period => Overlaps(period.Field<DateTime>("StartDate"), period.Field<DateTime>("EndDate"), startDate, endDate)).ToDataTable();
```

NOTE: If you don't need the answering `DataTable` for anything, it would be more efficient to replace `.ToDataTable()` with `.Any()` and just have the method return a `bool` indicating if any overlaps exist.